# Show notification specific message with CKSubscription / CKNotificationInfo?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I want to notify user that a chat message has been sent from an other user, and the body of the notification should be the message. Is it a way to set it with `CKSubscription` / `CKNotificationInfo`? Like `alertBody`, but specific for each message. Any idea how?

```
let s2 = CKSubscription(recordType: recordType, predicate: NSPredicate(format: "destination = %@", CKReference(recordID: CKRecordID(recordName: loggedInUserSettingRecordName!), action: .DeleteSelf)), options: .FiresOnRecordCreation)
s2.notificationInfo = CKNotificationInfo()
s2.notificationInfo.alertBody = " "
s2.notificationInfo.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
subscriptionsToSave.append(s2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parameters in your alert like this:

```
s2.notificationInfo.alertLocalizationKey = "Message from %1$@ : %2$@"
s2.notificationInfo.alertLocalizationArgs = ["FromName", "Text"]
```

Since this is a lokalized message you also need to add it to Localizable.strings

```
"Message from %1$@ %2$@ : %1$@" = "Message from %1$@ %2$@ : %1$@";
```

Comment: Anyway to make it record based? For example: one subscription for messages from `n` friends. If particular friend wrote, we show alert with his particular name? Looks like it's impossible now, I treat it like push notifications...